# Using Groupby with additional filter

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by

I have the data in Initial format:

[image]

***STEP 1:** To find out the users having more than 1 record and show those records*. This was achieved using the below.

```
SELECT ID,
       USER,
       STATUS
FROM TABLE
WHERE USER in
    (SELECT USER
     FROM TABLE
     GROUP BY USER
     HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
```

***STEP 2:** From the above set of records find out records for which all the values are either 1 or 2. SO data should be something like:

[image]

Can I get some suggestions to how to achieve that. Note status is `NVARCHAR` hence aggregate functions can't be used.

Comment: isnt having count(*) in (1,2) not working?

Comment: You probably need to convert your status to a numeric value - ideally you wouldn't store it as a string in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing is to check that the status is the same in your subquery.  Assuming that `status` only takes on the values `1` and `2`:

```
SELECT t.ID, t.USER, t.STATUS
FROM TABLE
WHERE t.USER IN (SELECT t2.USER
                 FROM TABLE t2
                 GROUP BY t2.USER
                 HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 AND
                        MIN(t2.status) = MAX(t2.status)
                );
```

If there are other status values and you particularly care about `1` and `2`, you would use:

```
SELECT t.ID, t.USER, t.STATUS
FROM TABLE
WHERE t.USER IN (SELECT t2.USER
                 FROM TABLE t2
                 GROUP BY t2.USER
                 HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 AND
                        MIN(t2.status) = MAX(t2.status) AND
                        MIN(t2.status) IN (1, 2)
                );
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check if this helps

```
 SELECT ID,
   [USER],
   [STATUS]
 FROM TABLE
 WHERE [USER] in
(SELECT [USER]
 FROM TABLE
 GROUP BY [USER]
 HAVING COUNT([USER]) > 1 AND ((MIN(STATUS) != MAX(STATUS) AND COUNT(STATUS) > 2) OR (MIN(STATUS) = MAX(STATUS))))
```